# How to fix the dependencies in order to parse an XML file?

Tags: java, xml, maven, automation

I have searched stackoverflow on how to fix this, but nothing fixes it.

The code keeps breaking on line 166. I believe it has something to do with my pom file, but I cant figure out how to fix it.

```
160         DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
161         System.out.println("DB is"+db);
DB isorg.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl@763334fe

162         InputSource is = new InputSource();
163         System.out.println("is= "+is);
is= org.xml.sax.InputSource@7fc7ed31

164         is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(strXMLResponse));
165         System.out.println("strXMLResponse" + strXMLResponse);
strXMLResponse

166         Document doc = db.parse("is"+is);
167         System.out.println("doc"+doc);

168         nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Value");
169         System.out.println("node"+nodes);
```

This is my pom file: I'm using jdk 17.0.4.1. Java

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>
  
    <dependency>                
         <groupId>junit</groupId>                               
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>                             
         <version>3.8.1</version>                               
         <scope>test</scope>                                
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
<target.dir>target2</target.dir>
```

I have changed the pom dependencies and import statements. I have looked in stackoverflow to find the answer, but nothing works.

Comment: ("is"+is) doesn't look like the correct parameter.  Why not just (is)?

Comment: The code works on a different machine, with an older jdk version. That's why I think it's a pom issue that needs to be updated. I just cant find it.

Comment: What does "breaking on line 166" mean? Add full details. However as pcalkins points out you are passing in String "is=org.xml.sax.InputSource@7fc7ed31" not an InputSource.

Comment: It is possible that DocumentBuilder was removed from later versions of Java... but if that were the case, you'd have IDE errors on line 160.  It's also possible that DocumentBuilder's parse method changed (or "Document" type) in later versions, but still that argument looks wrong.  Seems like you'd want to pass in the stream.  Your POM includes 2 different libraries for XML though... I'd remove those so you use Java's XML parser.

Comment: If the version of Java you are using doesn't include an XML parser, go with 1 library for XML parsing otherwise you may have namespace issues.

Comment: `The code keeps breaking on line 166` this is not very descriptive, can you please post your stack trace or whatever error message

Answer (score 0):

If that's your POM file, then your code is breaking because it's not well-formed XML, for example it has a `</dependencies>` end tag with no corresponding start tag.

However, because you haven't given any error messages or other diagnostics, we can only guess. [I can only think that you omitted the diagnostics because they didn't help you. That doesn't mean they won't help someone else.]